# Converting any file to binary 1 and 0 and then back to original file without corruption in python

Tags: python, string, algorithm, binary, low-level

I need a bit help here, don't ask me why it is a wild idea but I want to convert any file into pure binary code 1 and 0 and then back to the original file. The requirement is that when converted the binary code need to be stored in a string data type in a variable and the function that takes in the binary code also accepts the code in a string data type. I would appreciate the solution in python but other languages are also welcome.

I tried to do it but when I converted back to the original file it was always corrupted. I tried to convert it to Hex and then to binary but I was not able to achieve that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Make sure you open both input and output files with the `'b'` flag.

Comment: You mean like hexdump and undump, but for base 2 using ASCII `'0'` and `'1'`, instead of base 16?  Algorithmically, there's very little difference, except in languages where there's special support for turning binary data into hex strings but not base-2 strings.  Python can do either base for you so you don't need to manually break into integers to shift and AND to extract bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example Python code that can convert any file to a string of binary code and then back to the original file:

```
def file_to_binary_string(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        binary_code = file.read()
        binary_string = ''.join(format(byte, '08b') for byte in binary_code)
    return binary_string
def binary_string_to_file(binary_string, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
        bytes_list = [int(binary_string[i:i+8], 2) for i in range(0, len(binary_string), 8)]
        bytes_arr = bytearray(bytes_list)
        file.write(bytes_arr)
# Usage example
file_path = 'example.pdf'
binary_string = file_to_binary_string(file_path)
binary_string_to_file(binary_string, 'new_example.pdf')
```